# Showing that Moore space of type$(G,2)$ is a suspension.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am reading this paper :

> [image]

But I am having a hard time understanding The following proof of showing that Moore space of type$(G,2)$ is a suspension.

> [image]

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- Why the order of the proof looks like that?

2- where is the definition of $f|S_{j}^1,$ I do not understand it?

3- why the reduced homologies of the mapping cone looks like that?

Could anyone help me answer those questions, please?

Comment: What textbooks did you use to learn algebraic topology?

Comment: @ConnorMalin I started by AT and Jeffery Strom. But now I am using Martin Arkowitz book and sometimes Rotman